# How to validate the MAX value of the table?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
query = "SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [Events]";
DataTable dt = execute(query);
DateTime date;

if (dt!= null && dt.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    date = (DateTime) dt.Rows[0][0];
}
else
{
    date = DateTime.Now;
}
```

now what is my question, when the table Events is empty, it returns me some invalid value, which is not even null...how can i write a normal validation for it?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need a DataTable? ExecuteScalar would be simpler/more efficient.

Comment: If the table is empty then you can use something like query = "SELECT isnull(MAX([Date], curdate()) FROM [Events]"; assuming mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is probably **DBNull.Value**, you could check for that, but out of the box, you could adapt the query (Assuming sql server): `SELECT isnull(MAX([Date]),getdate()) FROM [Events]`
That way, the value returned is always a valid datetime and the check can be omitted

Answer (score 0):

```
       SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [Events]",ConnectionObject);
```

int _value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

while(_value!=0)

{

//do something

_value--;
}